# Run shell script each time any user logs on

Tags: ubuntu, shell

I have a shell script that I want to be run each time a user logs on. I use Ubuntu as the OS.
The script should be run after user logon in ubuntu.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Ubuntu, any script ending in `.sh` that's placed in `/etc/profile.d/` will be run whenever a user logs in. That's what lines 4-11 of `/etc/profile` do.

Answer (score 2):

take a look at /etc/profile

Comment: Yes i have look at that, but i can't figure out where to put my shell script path so it should be run when user has logon to the computer.

Comment: all files in /etc/profile.d/ are executed automatically, you dont have to setup an specail script path (whatever this should be)